# XSL - Is there a way I can make this template reusable?

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

XSL noob here :-)

I've got the following template which is being used to produce a dropdown for my ANT script.

```
    <!-- Dropdown templates -->
<xsl:template name="componentDropdown">
    <xsl:text>trunk</xsl:text>
    <!-- Branch Data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="document('../../../temp/components_branches.xml')/lists/list/entry">
        <xsl:sort select="commit/@revision" order="descending" />
        <xsl:text>;branches/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- Tag Data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="document('../../../temp/components_tags.xml')/lists/list/entry">
        <xsl:sort select="commit/@revision" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="name != 'archive'">
            <xsl:text>;tags/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </xsl:if>               
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The thing is that I've got this three times over - cut & paste job - all the same but the reference to "components" is being swapped for "plugins" and "website". We've got a few more ANT scripts I'd like to migrate to this as well so ideally I'd like this as a reusable function-based template of some kind.

Working in progress but I've currently got the following:-

```
    <xsl:template name="dropdown">
    <xsl:param name="type">website</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="path"></xsl:param>

    <!-- Branch Data  -->
    <xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$path" /></xsl:text>       
    <xsl:for-each select="document(concat('../../../temp/{$type}_tags.xml',''))/lists/list/entry">
        <xsl:sort select="commit/@revision" order="descending" />
        <xsl:text>;branches/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The issue seems to be getting the documnet() function to accept dynamic variables.

Only other thing I can say is the XSL is declared as 1.0. I don't know if that makes a difference but any pointers are appreciated :).

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `document()` works properly, you need to concatenate as follows:

```
 document(concat('../../../temp/',$type,'_tags.xml',''))
```

Comment: Thanks empo :-). It's the simple answers that sometimes get missed.

Comment: The rule to remember is: never use curly braces /inside/ an XPath expression, only use them to delimit an XPath expression nested within literal text.